# Is it possible to use SELECT * in prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is it possible to use `*` in query for `$stmt->prepare()` and using `bind_result()`?
For example I have to select 50 columns in 1 table with conditions as parameter, and if I type all 50 columns it will take time.
So in this scenario how can I get the result?

```
$stmt->prepare("Select * from table where col1 = ? and col2=? and col3=? and col4=?")
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$col1, $col2, $col3, $col4)
$stmt->execute()
```

Comment: Typing all 50 columns will take time once. NOT typing all 50 columns will take extra time everytime the query is executed. Your choice.

Comment: also not typing the 50 column names on the first time may take hours and hours of additional debugging time later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course.
Just use `$res = $stmt->get_result()` followed by familiar `$row = $res->fetch_assoc()` stuff

However, for a newbie, you are indeed strictly advised to choose PDO over mysqli.

Comment: after reading this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons. PDO is a lot better than mysqli. so I guess I have to change my application.

Answer (score 0):

Only the question mark is used as a placeholder character by mysqli, so you can use * just as you usually would.

Answer (score -1):

To save time, if you are using PDO, you can name your parameters and then mass assign them.
E.g.

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE col1=:myval OR col2=:myval OR col3=:myval';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':myval ' => 150));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Updated my answer. I completely missed that mysqli keyword (mistook it for mysql) and assumed PDO due to the prepare statement